# Type Error In Haskell Function

Tags: haskell, substitution, unification

I've written a Haskell function like so:

```
shift :: Subst a -> Subst a
shift (S s) = [(x, (subst s' d)) | (x,d) <- s] where 
      s' = [(x,d) | (x,d) <- s, null (vars d)]
```

With a data type like so `data Subst a = S [(String,a)]`

I've declared `subst` as `subst :: Subst a -> a -> a` and `vars` as`vars :: a -> [String]`. When I run this, I get a type error. Any ideas why?

Comment: When you ask this sort of question **give us the error message**. The error messages are trying to help the programmer understand what's wrong. Even if they don't mean anything to you, they will help SO help you. And then, once you've gotten your answer, look at the error message and try to figure out how it corresponds to the explanation of your problem. That will gradually give you the ability to use type error messages to identify the problem for yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `shift` function is declared to return a `Subst`, but it really returns a list. You probably meant to wrap the `Subst` constructor around the list.

Then your `subst` function is declared to take a `Subst` argument, but you're calling it with a list - same issue basically.

Also your `vars` function probably contains a type error as well because, as I indicated in my answer to your previous question, you can't define a meaningful function of type `a -> [String]`.

Comment: yep you were right, that's what I was missing. Fixed now. Thanks!